# Capturing field name from assignment statements with Regex

Tags: regex

I have some Regex that separates some field names from an assignment expression. Up until now the field names have been sane enough that the regex works without issues, but now that the field names are using illegal characters (from the languages syntax point of view, AS3 in this case) the regex I developed is struggling. Its probably best if I give you a before, after, and details of the issue.

My current regex looks like this: `this\.(.*)?[=,]`. Up until now it has worked as the field names didn't contain either `=` or `,` characters. However now the code seems to be obfuscated with something that is causing field names to become illegal and It doesn't work. Before the assignment expression looked something like:

`this._-E12=_arg1.readInt();`

Back then the regex worked find and captured `_-E12`. Now the assignment expressions look like this:

`this.^"-=,#I.readInt();`

As you could imagine the regex doesn't like this much and captures `^"-=` where it should in fact capture `^"-` instead. The `,` in the regex is there for a reason as well as it's used to match lines like: `_arg1.readBytes(this._-E12, 0, count);`.

What I think I'm looking for is some way to find the last instance of the `=` character but that also would be a less than perfect solution as there is no way to promise that we won't get a line that looks like: `this.^"-=,=I.readInt();`.

This may be a stupid question and there may be no way to do this in Regex, but with all the amazing people out there, and the size of the regex people have written, I'm sure there has to be something!

---

For some more specific examples, here is what I'm looking for:

`this.^"-=,#I.readInt();` would match `^"-`

`arg1.readBytes(this.^"-, 0, count);` would match `^"-`

`this.0$R=readInt();` would match `0$R`

`arg1.readBytes(this.0$R, 0, count);` would match `0$R`

`this.^=s=readInt();` would match `^=s`

`arg1.readBytes(this.^=s, 0, count);` would match `^=s`

`this.$s==readInt();` would match `$s=`

`arg1.readBytes(this.$s=, 0, count);` would match `$s=`

Comment: This is probably doable with a regexp, but you're going to have to give a precise description of what to look for. How do you know whether the `=` or the `,` ends the field name?

Comment: I don't know which one does which is my issue. I don't think Regex can do this without using two separate expressions and testing if either matches.

Comment: If you can't tell where the field name ends, how can you possibly program the computer to do it? And how are we supposed to help you if you can't explain what you need clearly?

Comment: Oh I know how to tell... But I'm not sure how to "program" the computer to do it. I maybe able to use more specific regex once I know which one is used. I can probably test for a starting `(` before the `this`. To answer your question on how to tell if it ends in a `=` or `,`, the statement will only end in a `,` if there is a `(` before `this` other than that it will always end in a `=`.

Comment: Are you saying it could be `_arg1.readBytes(this._-E12=, 0, count);` and then the `=` will be part of the field name?

Comment: @Barmar Yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it, using positive and negative lookarounds:

```
(?<=\(this\.).*?(?=,)|(?<=(?<!\()this\.).*(?==)
```

Notice that I use a non-greedy wildcard before `,`, otherwise it will capture multiple arguments to the function. But I use a greedy wildcard before `=` so that it will find the last `=`.

[Regexr test](http://regexr.com?34pqe) gives the correct answer for all your examples. Whether it will work in the more general case, I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks! Your edited post works now :) I'll run it through our unit tests and then let you know! Thanks man!

Comment: Alright, it works in a really general case however there is one more specific case I'd like to ask about, let me edit my question.

Comment: Works in most cases except the following: `this.faction=,#I.getInstance().createInstance(param1.readShort()) as 7$=;` It matches everything upto the last $.

Comment: You said when it doesn't start with `(`, it should match up to the last `=`. What part of that should be changed to prevent this?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant the last "=" in the field name. What I meant is the assignment character, bascially if you looked at this from a programming point of view, it would look like: `this.faction = ,#I.getInstance().createInstance(param1.readShort()) as 7$=;` where it would match just faction.

Comment: Your description is circular. We're trying to determine where the field name ends, so you can't say "last = in the field name". Are there characters that are not allowed to be part of a field name? Change `.` to `[^listofnonfieldcharacters]`.

Comment: From a programming point of view, I wouldn't expect `=` to be part of a field name. But you have an example `this.$s==...` where the first `=` is part of the field name and the second one is the assignment operator. That's what makes this really confusing, so where the field name ends is not obvious.

Comment: Well, normally there would be, normally the "=" sign cannot be in the field name but because its obfuscated it has illegal characters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29532/discussion-between-barmar-and-jduncanator)

Comment: Waited for you for 10 minutes in the chat room. You need to provide a more precise definition of what constitutes a possible field name. Or, as Richard said in his comment, you need to write a real parser instead of a regexp kludge.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've gotten something working, I plan to just pad all the `=` that is actually the assignment character with a space, that way I can write a more simple regex. sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Matching the last instance of a character like `=` is possible:

```
.*=[^=]*
```

Zero or more of anything, followed by an `=` and then zero or more non-`=` characters.

However you need to clearly specify the cases you want to match: eg. which `=` should be matched as the field/value in these extreme cases.

Comment: @jduncanator Examples are not a specification, only a hint at a specification. Also what is the context? In the "function call" cases have the "parameters" are already been separated out? (The background question: are you trying to avoid writing a parser?)